# How to manipulate json file in Python

Tags: python, json

I want to pull data from here:
http://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?callback=?&cmd=getMakes

Here's my python script so far:

```
import urllib.request
import json
url =("http://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?callback=?&cmd=getMakes")
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
result = response.read().decode('utf-8')
print (result)
```

When I try to manipulate the resultes, starting with:

```
d = json.loads(result)
```

I get an error message: "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the output of  `print(result)`?

Comment: You're going to save yourself A LOT of headaches if you use python's requests library rather than urllib to make http requests.  You should provide the json data in your post.

Comment: just ran your code, the result is a json string wrapped in `()`. strip the enclosing parentheses and then you should be able to load the json. also, consider using `requests` instead of `urllib`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL/query is wrong; you are not getting a valid JSON reply back from the server; it starts like this:

```
?({"Makes":[{"make_id":"abarth","make_display":"Abarth","make_is_common":"0","make_country":"Italy"},
```

If you modify url like this:

```
url = ("http://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?cmd=getMakes")
```

it should work. At least it worked for me after that.

Apparently, the `callback=?` is meant such that the client can insert a callback method which gets passed the json. I.e. you can have the server generate executable javascript rather than just json.

Answer (score 0):

If I click your URL, the first characters in the body are "?(".  That's corrupting your attempt to feed it into JSON.  You will need to pre-process the data to strip out the junk.  There is also junk at the end.

Save yourself headaches by using Python requests library rather than urllib, by the way!